# Copy only public schema from Supabase to local db?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

How copy data from only public schema from Supabase database and paste it to a new local PostgreSQL database?

I tried with Snaplet but save only transformed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that can copy remote db to local db.

First backup your old database:

```sql
supabase db dump --db-url "$OLD_DB_URL" -f roles.sql --role-only
supabase db dump --db-url "$OLD_DB_URL" -f schema.sql
supabase db dump --db-url "$OLD_DB_URL" -f data.sql --data-only
```

Restore to your local db:

```sql
psql \
  --single-transaction \
  --variable ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
  --file schema.sql \
  --file data.sql \
  --dbname "$NEW_DB_URL"
```

`$OLD_DB_URL` is your remote project's database URL.

`$NEW_DB_URL` is your local database URL

Comment: Thanks!. You fotgot to mention the source of your answer: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/migrating-and-upgrading-projects#backup-your-old-database

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Supabase CLI. Once you have a local Supabase project setup, you can call the following commands.

```bash
# initialize a local project.
supabase init

# Link the local project to the remote project
supabase link --project-ref YOUR_PROJECT_REF_HERE

# Get the migration SQL script from the remote instance
supabase db diff --linked --use-migra
```

Comment: I get "Error: Authorization failed for the access token and project ref pair: {"message":"Forbidden resource"}" after running `supabase link --project-ref`. Any idea?

Comment: @Capy No idea what might be causing it. if it's happening to the latest version of Supabase CLI, would you open an issue on the Supabase CLI repo?